# scroll then fix div jumps on larger screen sizes

Tags: javascript, css, position, css-position

I have an element for which I've implemented a "scroll then fix" behavior-- when the user scrolls past a certain point, the div's position changes from relative to fixed, and the rest of the content on the page scrolls over it.

It seems to be working just fine, until I resize my window to about 1700px and above-- the div jumps a bit after it gets the class assigning it position:fixed, or it seems to get the position:fixed class after it actually should.

If anyone has any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong, or what could be causing this inconsistent behavior, I would appreciate it!

JS:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

        if (window.scrollY >= 50 ){
            $('.carousel').addClass("fixed");

        } else {

            $('.carousel').removeClass("fixed");
        }

    }
```

LESS:

```
.carousel{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
   &.fixed{
     position:fixed;
     top:-50px;
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you create a Fiddle or Ply for this?

Comment: https://codepen.io/lisakb/pen/pozrbwo This is basically it...but the behavior is much smoother here. Could be because of the images, content, etc that is slowing it down.

Comment: I'm slightly confused, do you want the `content here` to still be displayed or just the fact that it jumps?

Comment: It's jumping because once you set it to fixed, it automatically goes back to `top: 0;` then will quickly do `top: -50px;` I think it may look better if you were to just keep it fixed and then just do `top: -50px;` when they've scrolled down a little.

Comment: @HaldenCollier I actually do need it to scroll up a little bit initially, so I can't start with position fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `position: sticky;` for this. Simply replace `absolute` with `sticky` in the `.carousel` class and remove all the JS logic. As this approach is pure CSS, you will have a smooth experience.

```
.carousel {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #840202;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Just note, this attribute isn't [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky)

Comment: This would be perfect but I think the browser support issue is a bit of a dealbreaker.

Comment: I think all the modern browsers currently support sticky with the exception of Internet Explorer, opera mini and blackberry browser. If you are targeting 100% coverage then maybe yeah. Fun Fact:-  left sidebar of stackoverflow uses position: sticky.